# Unable to Match numbers only using Regular Expression in golang using Regex

Tags: go

```
matched, err := regexp.MatchString(`[0-9]`, `a.31`)
fmt.Println(matched)
```

The above expression is returning true.. Isn't it supposed to be false?

I want to extract only numbers but why is "a.31" considered true? I've noticed that having atleast a number in the string will return "true"...

How to make it return "true" only for numbers?

Comment: It matches the one digit '3' as you asked using `[0-9]`. How many digits you want to match? space? What about position of digits inside of this string? for example try `^[0-9]+$`

Comment: @wasmup `^[0-9]+$` solves the problem... Recognizes only digits... Thank you..